# Probablity of passing a test knowing only a portion of the answers

Tags: probability

My lecturer has provided us with 16 possible questions, 4 of which will appear on an exam where we answer 3 out of the 4 questions.

I would be happy answering 2 questions correctly.

How many of the 16 possible questions can I eliminate from my study to answer those 2 questions correctly?

Comment: Is this a question for a probability course?

Comment: So you have to make sure that of the 16 questions you study $n$ so that however the 4 in the exam are selected you have done at least 2. That you have to answer only 3 makes no difference. Consider an opponent who wants to harm you as much as possible, he will select all questions you did not study. This shows you must know at least $16 - (4 - 2) = 14$ questions to guarantee 2 correct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all at first you mentioned 16 questions but later you said 14, I will just answer assuming you meant 16.

Think of it this way, if you plan on answering 2 out of 4 questions on the exam, then you are actually planning to leave **2 questions unanswered**. These two questions (whichever they are) are the ones you technically don't want to study for. So if out of the 16 possible questions, there are only 2 that you do not need to study for, then you must actually study 14 out of the 16 questions.

Edit: The probability of passing is as follows (assuming each question is worth 25%, you answer all questions you studied for correctly, and the passing grade is 50%): If you study 14 out of the 16 questions like I mentioned then you have a 100% chance of answering *at least* 2 out of the 4 given exam questions. So you pass with 100% certainty.

Let's say you decide to only study 1 out of 16 questions, you will 100% fail. Because even if the question you studied appears on the test, your grade will be 25% (In the best case).

If you decide to only study let's say 7 out of the 16 questions. 
Now you open your exam... The first question has a 7/16 chance of being a question you studied for. If it was a question you studied for, then the second question has a 6/15 chance of being a question you studied for. 
So the chance you get a 2 questions you studied for is 17.5%

You can repeat this calculation with the following formula. Let n = number of questions you studied for, m = number of questions on the exam. (Assuming again you only want to answer 2 questions correctly)

probability in percentage = n/m * (n-1)/(m-1) * 100

Answer (score 1):

If you study 13 of the 16 questions, then it would be possible for the exam to contain the missing three questions, and you would only get one right.  But if you study 14 questions, you will be guaranteed to know at least two questions on the exam.

Answer (score 1):

You must study 14 questions in order to guarantee being able to comfortably answer 2. If you study 14 questions, the worst case scenario is that 2 questions are chosen that you cannot answer, and 2 questions are chosen that you can answer. You then answer the questions you can.

However, the *probability* that this happens is a more difficult and interesting question.